# ValueError: 'ITEM' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous

Tags: python, geopandas, data-frame, geodataframe

I'm trying to process some data, with geopandas0.9.

Here is my code:

```
locations = select_polygons.groupby(class_col).apply(lambda x: \
            sample_locations_from_polygon(x, sample_on_boundary='road'
            in x[class_col].iloc[0].lower() or 'railway'
            in x[class_col].iloc[0].lower()))
    return locations
```

Here `class_col="ITEM"`

It gives me error saying: **`ValueError: 'ITEM' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`**

Here is what the data looks like: https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/611f82f63ceb64bb00c117116897323e#file-dump-md

Couldn't paste it here, due to it's extensive size.

How can I resolve this? I'm fresh in GIS.

I've tried this:

```
class_col='_ITEM'
    locations = select_polygons.groupby(class_col).apply(lambda x: \
            sample_locations_from_polygon(x, sample_on_boundary='road'
            in x[class_col].iloc[0].lower() or 'railway'
            in x[class_col].iloc[0].lower()))
    return locations
```

Then it says: **`KeyError: '_ITEM'`**

I've also tried setting the index, manually

```
select_polygons.set_index('_ITEM')
```

But that raises another error, saying:
**`"None of ['_ITEM'] are in the columns"`**

Comment: Is the `sample_locations_from_polygon` function something that you created yourself? If so, what does its body look like? If not, where is it imported from?

Comment: Looks like this is the source of that function? https://github.com/adrianalbert/urban-environments/blob/master/dataset-collection/urbanatlas.py

Comment: the source is from urban-atlas, I;ve updated the question... can you guys check again.